# Net::HTTP::Get timeout issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

Trying to tun a simple chunk of code form index controller action.
But get Net::ReadTimeout error.

```
class PaymentMethodsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    uri = URI.parse("http://localhost:3000")
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new("/api/user/profile/payment", {'Content-Type' =>'application/json'})
    request.set_form_data({token: 'vjuri@mrd.com:CFTKGNZKXC'})
    res = http.request(request)

    render text: res.body
  end
end
```

From rails console it works like a charm.

```
2.1.2 :027 > uri = URI.parse("http://localhost:3000") => #<URI::HTTP:0x00000004d0eb80 URL:http://localhost:3000> 
2.1.2 :028 > http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port) => #<Net::HTTP localhost:3000 open=false> 
2.1.2 :029 > request = Net::HTTP::Get.new("/api/user/profile/payment", {'Content-Type' =>'application/json'})
 => #<Net::HTTP::Get GET> 
2.1.2 :031 >  request.set_form_data({token: 'vjuri@mrd.com:CFTKGNZKXC'})
 => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
2.1.2 :032 > res = http.request(request)
 => #<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true> 
2.1.2 :033 > res.body
 => "{\"result\":{\"errorcode\":0,\"errormessage\":\"\",\"payments\":[]}}"
```

How to force Net::HTTP work from controller?

Answer (score 1):

This is the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970242/using-nethttp-within-rails-to-hit-rails) on my question.
The reason is

> It doesn't work because you are not using a multi-threaded server.
>   Your request is coming in and blocking the server until it's complete.
>   During that time, you're making a request to your localhost that isn't
>   being handled.